# Simplify math division: getting from $\frac1{\frac1x+1}$ to $\frac{x}{x+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't rest my mind for not knowing how to solve the problem I have. Have thought about it since the afternoon. I know the solution but I don't have a clue on how to do it. If you could help me, that would be great.

The problem is to simplify $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+1}$. I know that the answer is $\frac{x}{x+1}$ but I can't figure out why.

Comment: One may always "multiply by one" and "add by zero" without fear of changing anything (*except possibly for division by zero errors*).  The "trick" is *how you write one* and *how you write zero*.  Remember that any number divided by itself is equal to one, so by multiplying by a number divided by itself we don't change the value.  Further, a number minus itself is equal to zero, so by adding and subtracting the same thing we don't change the value either.

Comment: (*Small technical detail: in your original expression $x=0$ and $x=-1$ both result in an undefined expression due to a division by zero error.  In your modified expression, only $x=-1$ results in an undefined expression, so in that sense these are different expressions.  They are equal everywhere except at $x=0$ and $x=-1$*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Multiply the top and bottom of the expression by $x$

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple: reduce the terms in the denominator to the same denominator, then use that $$\Bigl(\frac ab \Bigr)^{-1}=\frac ba.$$

Answer (score 0):

For $x\not=0$, $x\not=-1:$

Denominator: $(1/x) +1 = \dfrac{x+1}{x}.$
Numerator:$1$

$\dfrac{Numerator}{Denominator} =$

$ \dfrac{1}{\Big (\dfrac{x+1}{x}\Big )}=1×\dfrac{x}{x+1}=$

$\dfrac{x}{x+1}.$